# There is an inconsistency in the DS, suggest you run dcdiag in a few moments, perhaps on a different DC

Tags: replication, domain-controller, active-directory

Performing initial setup:

- Connecting to directory service on server .
- Collecting site info.
- Identifying all servers.
- **ERROR: There is an inconsistency in the DS, suggest you run dcdiag in a few moments, perhaps on a different DC.

I have made sure the support tools are up to date as well. This is happening on ALL the servers on the domain - ideas? Thanks!

Comment: What setup is being run here, that isn't clear.

Comment: There's about 25-30 DC's within our Forest. All are receiving this error. I'm starting to think it's an issue with our domain health.

Comment: Also this is running dcdiag.exe I get this error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dug a little deeper, Directory Services error log shows 1864 errors. So looks like we have some lingering objects and AD needs a serious cleanup.